# magento2: unknown query INSERT INTO "search_tmp..."

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2

recently i've done mass attribute update and noticed that i got new processes in DB, like that:

```
INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5b069a25b016d1_83026725` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0) + (0) + (0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score`
```

problem is that the never-ending, they slowing down the server and what is most important - they creating new same processes until server reaches pm.max_children parameter value and PHP-fpm die.

please advise what is nature of this processes and how to kill it completely? (if I kill existing ones - new are borns after some time)

p.s. indexer processes are not running.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal magento2 behaviour to store api type documents and pre-rendered attributes.

Please see the following classes:

`Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Advanced\Collection`

`Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection`

`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Aggregation\Builder`

`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Mapper`

`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorage`

`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\TemporaryStorageFactory.php`

see: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9c14af7a97bcf338662de365d2613c7ca9dbf8c6/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Search/Adapter/Mysql/TemporaryStorage.php#L20

Due to your mass attribute update, the Observer that listens to the event controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save is triggered to initiate re-indexing of the products updated in the mass-update.

```
<event name="controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save">
    <observer name="flush_varnish_pagecache" instance="Magento\CacheInvalidate\Observer\InvalidateVarnishObserver"/>
</event>
```

in `magento/module-cache-invalidate/etc/events.xml`

Comment: yes, but product was re-indexed couple days ago, but this processes still running, i guess this is not normal...

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Due to any attribute-update this is triggered. It does not matter when the last index took place. Upon change it triggers the indexer.

Comment: Depending on the size of your product collection and the server infrastructure this could take some time

Comment: there is definitely misunderstanding :)
yes, i meant that mass attribute change really triggers reindexing processes, but them finished successfully in few hours, while sql queriers still running. is it normal?

Comment: Yes,  the queries may continue to run and take some extra time to finish after your mass update has run.

Comment: it's running about one week, i guess it's not normal. pls advice how to kill them properly?

Comment: we dont want the magento search , we using dofinder search but site is down just because of INSERT INTO `search_tmp_5b069a25b016d1_83026725` how we can solve that??

Comment: I am also facing the same issue is there any way to solve this?